# Create content in chinese language in drupal 7?

Tags: nodes, i18n-l10n

I want to create content in Chinese language manually in drupal 7 just by inserting translated text into body, without using any module like internationalization. Kindly suggest any solution ? Do I need to add language support for chines by using 'locale' module ?

Comment: You can simply type Chinese text in the node body directly...

Comment: Thanks Patrick Kenny but there would be a risk of data corruption by this method. Isn't it ?

Answer (score 2):

See [how to install a language](https://drupal.org/node/21145) on Drupal.org.  After installing and enabling Chinese as a language, you will be able to specify that a node is a Chinese language node when creating/editing it.

There is no risk of data corruption, but in order to avoid problems, **never change the default language** (as quoted from the documentation).